# How to make so I don't have to save everytime to run a single code in python VSC

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Hi I'm a newbie to python and I was wondering as exactly as the title of this post/question. Everytime I save my file, and open it, whenever I change the code, it runs the same as my previous code as if I haven't changed it.
And now, everytime I want to run a code, I have to save it and it's kinda tedious.
I was wondering if there's an easy fix for this. Thank you.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Wvkp.jpg)

Comment: Set a Python Interpreter in VSCode and just use the "Run" option in VSCode to pass to the intepreter without using the terminal. More here https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments

Comment: Add `"files.autoSave": "afterDelay",` in **User Settings.json** can solve your question.